# Give me all elements in the array that have the same date, JS

Tags: javascript, lodash

So consider the following data:

```
{  
   post_views:[  
      {  
         id:1,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"xxx",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:2,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"yyy",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000"
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

How would get I get all elements that match: 2016-08-08 ??

**What have you tried?**

Lodashes, filter:

```
  let datesThatMatch = filter(this.state.data.post_views, (views) => {
    return moment(views.created_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY') === moment(views.created_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY')
  });

  console.log(datesThatMatch);
```

I don't care about what time of day they were created at, just as long as the day they were created on match.

help?

## Update

I just realized I am also going about this all wrong because while I only showed you a portion of the data, there are hundreds of these objects i the array (if not thousands) and the goal is to say, ok there are 16 matches for 2016-08-08, 50 matches for x date, 14 matches for y date which adds to the complexity of this filter.

Comment: Wait, that condition you have in the `filter` callback - is it really trying to get the exact same date compared on both sides?

Comment: This is easy, they both match, so just get all ?

Comment: @vld I dont understand your question. I just want to get all elements from the array that match the date in the specified format. Currently the array is empty when it returns.

Comment: @adeneo I only showed you a portion of the array of objects theres thousands. And all with different dates. these two just happen to have the same date, some have the same date, others do not.

Comment: Should both `created_at` and `updated_at` match that specific date, or do you want to return the ones where updated and created are the same day, or ...? It's very unclear.

Comment: @adeneo It is not very unclear the code as given shows that they should match on `created_at`. also note the update.

Comment: @TheWebs Well, you said you want to get all elements that are from **2016-08-08** but that's not what the `filter` callback does - it tries to compare the create date to the...create date. Shouldn't it compare the create date to **2016-08-08**?

Comment: @Vid No, the specific date in question is an example. It should filter on dates that match, so in this case we have two that have 2016-08-08. there are other dates in this array that are also duplicates. essentially I want to count up all the duplicates in this array. But I want them to come back as arrays of simmilars.

Comment: That makes no sense, you just said you wanted all that was `2016-08-08`, how are we supposed to guess what duplicates you have and how the rest of the data looks like ?

Comment: @TheWebs OK, so let's see if I got this right - you have an array of objects that have create dates and you want to collect all duplicates (that were created on the same day). Is that correct? E.g., `["2016-08-08", "2016-08-08 ", "2016-08-10", "2016-08-12", "2016-08-12"  ]` should return you something like `[ "2016-08-08", "2016-08-12"]` (only, full objects, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think groupBy is a better alternative based on your update:

```js
var data = {  
   post_views:[  
      {  
         id:1,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"xxx",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:2,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"yyy",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:3,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"zzz",
         created_at:"2016-08-12T20:15:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-12T21:20:00+0000"
      },
   ]
}
     
let groupedDatesThatMatch = _.groupBy(data.post_views, function(views) {
     return moment(views.created_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY')
});
     
console.log(groupedDatesThatMatch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You get an object of arrays out the other end

Comment: See this is the correct answer but it doesn't work for me, the `this.state.data.post_views` contains an array of objects. and the `groupedDatesThatMatch` is just an empty object.

Comment: The only oddity i saw was you were not referencing lodash in your sample, but 'filter'. You sure you have got lodash declared. After that you are going to have to throw in a debugger; or console.log to see what data the function is attempting to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a "reverse lookup table" (i.e, indicates where each key occurs)
Following is a sample demo;

```
 var a = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7];                                                                                                                           
 var reverseIndex = new Map();
 a.every((cVal, i, a) => {
   var existing = reverseIndex.has(cVal) ? reverseIndex.get(cVal) : [];
   existing.push(i);
   reverseIndex.set(cVal, existing);
   return true;
 });

console.log(reverseIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```js
let post_views = [  
      {  
         id:1,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"xxx",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:2,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"yyy",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000"
      }
   ]
  
let looking_for = new RegExp('2016-08-08')
 
let result = post_views.filter(view => looking_for.test(view.created_at) || looking_for.test(view.updated_at) )

let summary = result.reduce((prev,view) => { 
  
                  let created_at = view.created_at.split('T')[0];  
                  let updated_at = view.updated_at.split('T')[0];
  
                      prev.created_at[created_at] = prev.created_at[created_at] || 0;
                      prev.updated_at[updated_at] = prev.updated_at[updated_at] || 0;
                      prev.created_at[created_at]++;
                      prev.updated_at[updated_at]++;
  
                      return prev;  
                  },{ created_at: {}, updated_at: {} })

console.log(result);

console.log(summary);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some finagling, I managed to  come up with a solution that uses dateformat and allows you to customize the date on the fly easily. This uses no libraries, and straight ES6. If you run the snippet, you'll see that your dates match and are stored.

```js
const arr = {  
   post_views:[  
      {  
         id:1,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"xxx",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:22:45+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:2,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"yyy",
         created_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000"
      },
      {  
         id:3,
         post_id:5,
         ip_address:"yyy",
         created_at:"2016-08-09T22:23:00+0000",
         updated_at:"2016-08-08T22:23:00+0000"
      },
   ]
}
const filterDate = new Date(2016, 08, 08);

function parseDate(date) {
  const dateString = date.split("T")[0].split('-'); //Get just the date portion, and then split that into an array.
  const newDate = new Date(Number(dateString[0]), Number(dateString[1]), Number(dateString[2])) //Make the new date object
  return newDate;
}

let myMatches = arr.post_views.filter(thisDate => parseDate(thisDate.created_at).getTime() == filterDate.getTime());

console.log(myMatches);
```